# why the sides of the waist hurt when running?

Tags: running, breathing

I've seen so many people, Including me, that when they start running for a couple of minutes, the sides of their waist hurt. I've heard that it's because they drank water before running and I've also heard that it's because they haven't drunk water during or before running. I think that may also be due to bad breathing, but I'm not sure.

This doesn't happen every time I start running. For instance, I do workouts 3 times a week and sometimes this happens to me once or twice a week.

Comment: [That wasn't so hard now, was it?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_stitch)

Comment: i wish i knew what you mean by that

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla is linking you to the most common source of side pain when exercising. Does it match what you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per LarissaGodzilla's comment, this is likely an [exercise related transient abdominal pain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_stitch), commonly known as a "Side stitch". Surprisingly enough, no one knows for certain why they happen, but the Wikipedia article linked above gives some advice for how to avoid them.

Also: [What causes side stitches?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/what-causes-side-stitches) and [What to do against side stitch?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/what-to-do-against-side-stitch) on this site.

Comment: sorry the linked words didn't look blue to me to click on them! and that's the answer i guess. thanks

Comment: It's a learning experience. Side stitches are considered relatively common knowledge around here, but my experience is that there are a number of misconceptions out there. Your question showed a degree of research, so I voted it up.

Comment: i always wanted to know the reason for that but now it seems more complicated than I've ever thought. thank you!